# Resize a Drawable to full screen

Tags: android, background, drawable, android-linearlayout

I'm downloading a bitmap from internet, then I cast this bitmap as a Drawable to set it as a background in my LinearLayout.

I see that unfortunately the image is scaled to fill the view, how can I scale the image until the smallest size reach the border (so it's not stretched)?
(And possibly centered)

I've tried something like this but without any success.
Am I on the way?

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.main);
        Drawable picture = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        picture.setBounds(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(picture);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this?

```
 setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Yes, but my image is not in an ImageView but is set as a background in the LinearLayout. Do you know if I can put an ImageView on the background (and put on it other views)?

Comment: Hmmm... thought so. I really love to use relative layouts (they are all about freedom ;)). Setting an ImageView as background and use with CENTER_CROP is one solution. But i can't think of a way to do this within a LinearLayout (if it is possible anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I think,It is not advisable use scaled images on an app. It's a best practice use a repeated pattern instead. So, I would try something like that:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/background-image-repeatable-pattern.png" 
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Save this to drawable/background.xml file (for example)